# How to watch store values from vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am using `vuex` and `vuejs 2` together.

I am new to `vuex`, I want to watch a `store` variable change.

I want to add the `watch` function in my `vue component`

This is what I have so far:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import {
  MY_STATE,
} from './../../mutation-types';

export default {
  [MY_STATE](state, token) {
    state.my_state = token;
  },
};
```

I want to know if there are any changes in the `my_state`

How do I watch `store.my_state` in my vuejs component?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You should not use component's watchers to listen to state change. I recommend you to use getters functions and then map them inside your component.

```js
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      myState: 'getMyState'
    })
  }
}
```

In your store:

```js
const getters = {
  getMyState: state => state.my_state
}
```

You should be able to listen to any changes made to your store by using `this.myState` in your component.

https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper

Comment: I don't know how to implement mapGetters. Can you point me to an example. It would be a big help. I just implement GONG answer at the moment.  TY

Comment: @Rbex "mapGetters" is part of 'vuex' library. You don't need to implement it.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen videos in vuex and I have already used vuex mapGetters  `computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      myState: 'getMyState'
    })
  }` that is the part that gives me error and I install babel. Now it works like a charm... TY

Comment: This works great along with vue-highcharts to provide real time moving chart.

Comment: @Gabriel Robert Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487276/how-can-i-send-data-from-parent-to-child-component-by-vuex-store-in-vue-componen

Comment: This answer is just wrong. He actually needs to watch the computed properties.

Comment: The getter once called will only retrieve the state at that time.  If you want that property to reflect the state change from another component you have to watch it.

Comment: Why "You should not use component's watchers to listen to state change"? 
Here is example you might not think of, if I want to watch on token from the state, and when it change to redirect to another page. so, there is some cases you need to do that. maybe you need more experience to know that.

Comment: This isn't enough. You must WATCH it in this case.

Answer (score 354):

Let's say, for example, that you have a basket of fruits,
and each time you add or remove a fruit from the basket, you
want to (1) display info about fruit count, **but** you also (2) want to be notified of the count of the fruits in some fancy fashion...

*fruit-count-component.vue*

```html
<template>
  <!-- We meet our first objective (1) by simply -->
  <!-- binding to the count property. -->
  <p>Fruits: {{ count }}</p>
</template>

<script>
import basket from '../resources/fruit-basket'

export default () {
  computed: {
    count () {
      return basket.state.fruits.length
      // Or return basket.getters.fruitsCount
      // (depends on your design decisions).
    }
  },
  watch: {
    count (newCount, oldCount) {
      // Our fancy notification (2).
      console.log(`We have ${newCount} fruits now, yay!`)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Please note, that the name of the function in the `watch` object, must match the name of the function in the `computed` object. In the example above the name is `count`.

New and old values of a watched property will be passed into watch callback (the count function) as parameters.

The basket store could look like this:

*fruit-basket.js*

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const basket = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    fruits: []
  },
  getters: {
    fruitsCount (state) {
      return state.fruits.length
    }
  }
  // Obviously you would need some mutations and actions,
  // but to make example cleaner I'll skip this part.
})

export default basket
```

You can read more in the following resources:

- [Computed properties and watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)
- [API docs: computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#computed)
- [API docs: watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch)

Comment: I am just wondering what shoul I do when the `watch` action should split into two steps: 1) First, checking if the the desire data is cached and if it does just return the cached data; 2) If the cache failed I need an async ajax action to fetch the data, but this seems to be the `action`'s work. Hoping my question make sense, thank you!

Comment: What is the benefit of this, over micah5's answer, which just sets a watcher in the component, on the store value? It has less code to maintain.

Comment: @Exocentric When I written the answer, question was not clear for me. There is no context why it is needed to watch properties. Think of it like: "I want to watch variable X, so I can do Y." Probably that is why most answers propose so vastly different approaches. No one knows what the intent is.

That is why I included "objectives" in my answer. If you have different objectives, different answer might fit them. My example is just a starting point for experimentation. It is not meant to be a plug & play solution.

There is no "benefit", because benefits depends on your situation.

Comment: @1Cr18Ni9 I think caching does not belong in component code. You will end up over-engineering something that should be really simple (fetching data and binding it to the view). Caching is already implemented in the browser. You can take advantage of it by sending correct headers from server. Simple explanation here: https://csswizardry.com/2019/03/cache-control-for-civilians/. You can also take a look at ServiceWorkers which allow for website to work even without internet connection.

Comment: Why do you have to watch the computed value? Why does the computed value not create a working watch for this value? That is after all the point of a computed value.

Answer (score 271):

It's as simple as:

```js
watch: {
  '$store.state.drawer': function() {
    console.log(this.$store.state.drawer)
  }
}
```

If the store is in a module, use:

```js
'$store.state.myModule.drawer'
```

For nested files, use:

```js
'$store.state.fileOne.fileTwo.myModule.drawer'
```

Comment: Would be even simplier if it was
`function(n) { console.log(n); }`

Comment: Interestingly, I first wrote `'this.$store.state.something'` and it didn't work so I assumed this wouldn't work... Didn't know that you need to leave out the `this` part! Could somebody explain it? I guess watchers already assume you're working on the Vue instance so `this` is unnecessary?

Comment: By the way, if the store is namespaced with modules, just write `'$store.state.module.something'`

Comment: how would I do it if I want to watch state in a nested vuex folder like `store/fileOne/fileTwo/fileThree/stateFile` ? @xji

Comment: @seyet just use '$store.state.fileOne.fileTwo.fileThree.stateFile.yourState'

Answer (score 60):

**As mentioned above it is not good idea to watch changes directly in store**

*But in some very rare cases it may be useful for someone, so i will leave this answer. For others cases, please see @gabriel-robert answer*

You can do this through `state.$watch`. Add this in your `created` (or where u need this to be executed) method in component

```js
this.$store.watch(
    function (state) {
        return state.my_state;
    },
    function () {
        //do something on data change
    },
    {
        deep: true //add this if u need to watch object properties change etc.
    }
);
```

More details: https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#watch

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to watch state directly. We should use getters. https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper

Comment: @GabrielRobert I think there's a place for both. If you need to reactively change template conditions based, using a computed value with mapState, etc makes sense. But otherwise, like for even flow control in a component, you need a full watch. You are right, you should not use plain component watchers, but the state.$watch is designed for these use cases

Comment: Everyone mentions it, but no one says why! I'm trying to build a vuex store that's auto-synchronised with a DB upon changes. I feel watchers on the store is the most frictionless way! What do you think? Still not a good idea?

Answer (score 22):

I think the asker wants to use watch with Vuex.

```
this.$store.watch(
      (state)=>{
        return this.$store.getters.your_getter
      },
      (val)=>{
       //something changed do something

      },
      {
        deep:true
      }
      );
```

Comment: Where should be this called?

Comment: somewhere that has access to the Vue instance through `this`. like, a `created` hook. Basically, any component you need

Answer (score 19):

This is for all the people that cannot solve their problem with getters and actually really need a watcher, e.g. to talk to non-vue third party stuff (see [Vue Watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on when to use watchers).

Vue component's watchers and computed values both also work on computed values. So it's no different with vuex:

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

export default {
    computed: {
        ...mapState(['somestate']),
        someComputedLocalState() {
            // is triggered whenever the store state changes
            return this.somestate + ' works too';
        }
    },
    watch: {
        somestate(val, oldVal) {
            // is triggered whenever the store state changes
            console.log('do stuff', val, oldVal);
        }
    }
}
```

if it's only about combining local and global state, the [mapState's doc](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html#the-mapstate-helper) also provides an example:

```
computed: {
    ...mapState({
        // to access local state with `this`, a normal function must be used
        countPlusLocalState (state) {
          return state.count + this.localCount
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: nice hack,  but just too tedious, don't you think?

Comment: It is not a hack if it's in the docs, is it? But then, it's not a pro-argument for vue/vuex either

Answer (score 14):

I tried literally everything to get this working.

### Theory

I found that for some reason, changes to objects from `$store` don't necessarily trigger a `.watch` method. My workaround was to

- Store

  - Create a complex data set which *should* but *doesn't* propagate changes to a Component
  - Create an incrementing counter in the `state` to act as a flag, which *does* propagate changes to a Component when watched
  - Create a method in `$store.mutators` to alter the complex dataset and increment the counter flag
- Component

  - Watch for changes in the `$store.state` flag. When change is detected, update locally relevant reactive changes from the `$store.state` complex data set
  - Make changes to the `$store.state`'s dataset using our `$store.mutators` method

### Implementation

This is implemented something like this:

**Store**

```js
let store = Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    counter: 0,
    data: { someKey: 0 }
  },
  mutations: {
    updateSomeKey(state, value) {
      update the state.data.someKey = value;
      state.counter++;
    }
  }
});
```

**Component**

```js
  data: {
    dataFromStoreDataSomeKey: null,
    someLocalValue: 1
  },
  watch: {
    '$store.state.counter': {
        immediate: true,
        handler() {
           // update locally relevant data
           this.someLocalValue = this.$store.state.data.someKey;
        }
     }
  },
  methods: {
    updateSomeKeyInStore() { 
       this.$store.commit('updateSomeKey', someLocalValue);
  }
```

### Runnable demo

It's convoluted but basically here we are watching for a flag to change and then updating local data to reflect important changes in an object that's stored in the `$state`

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    voteCounter: 0,
    // changes to objectData trigger a watch when keys are added,
    // but not when values are modified?
    votes: {
      'people': 0,
      'companies': 0,
      'total': 0,
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    vote(state, position) {
      state.votes[position]++;
      state.voteCounter++;
    }
  },
});


app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store: store,
  data: {
    votesForPeople: null,
    votesForCompanies: null,
    pendingVote: null,
  },
  computed: {
    totalVotes() {
      return this.votesForPeople + this.votesForCompanies
    },
    peoplePercent() {
      if (this.totalVotes > 0) {
        return 100 * this.votesForPeople / this.totalVotes
      } else {
        return 0
      }
    },
    companiesPercent() {
      if (this.totalVotes > 0) {
        return 100 * this.votesForCompanies / this.totalVotes
      } else {
        return 0
      }
    },
  },
  watch: {
    '$store.state.voteCounter': {
        immediate: true,
        handler() {
          // clone relevant data locally
          this.votesForPeople = this.$store.state.votes.people
          this.votesForCompanies = this.$store.state.votes.companies
        }
     }
  },
  methods: {
    vote(event) {
      if (this.pendingVote) {
        this.$store.commit('vote', this.pendingVote)
      }
    }
  }
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.5.1/dist/vuex.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div id="app">
   <form @submit.prevent="vote($event)">
      <div class="form-check">
         <input
           class="form-check-input" 
           type="radio" 
           name="vote" 
           id="voteCorps"
           value="companies"
           v-model="pendingVote"
          >
         <label class="form-check-label" for="voteCorps">
         Equal rights for companies
         </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
         <input
           class="form-check-input" 
           type="radio" 
           name="vote"
           id="votePeople" 
           value="people"
           v-model="pendingVote"
         >
         <label class="form-check-label" for="votePeople">
         Equal rights for people
         </label>
      </div>
      <button
        class="btn btn-primary"
        :disabled="pendingVote==null"
      >Vote</button>
   </form>
   <div
     class="progress mt-2"
     v-if="totalVotes > 0"
    >
      <div class="progress-bar"
        role="progressbar"
        aria-valuemin="0"
        :style="'width: ' + peoplePercent + '%'"
        :aria-aluenow="votesForPeople"
        :aria-valuemax="totalVotes"
      >People</div>
      <div
        class="progress-bar bg-success"
        role="progressbar"
        aria-valuemin="0"
        :style="'width: ' + companiesPercent + '%'"
        :aria-valuenow="votesForCompanies"
        :aria-valuemax="totalVotes"
      >Companies</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You ran into the reactivity caveat of Vue, which is pretty well documented: Once observed, you can no longer add reactive properties to the root data object. It is therefore recommended to declare all root-level reactive properties upfront, before creating the instance.

Comment: Meaning, changing `votes[xxx]` where xxx is not defined upfront will not give you reactivity of those value changes

Comment: More information about this issue and how to move around it: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects

Comment: @DerekPollard when I tried to use resolve this problem by creating a reactive component to manage the data as suggested in the docs you reference, I my project crashed with a **recursive loop counter exceeded**, which implies to me that the `$store.state`'s object is already reactive. Additionally, when I manually verified the `$store.state` data had changed *eg by button click*, the changes were reflected in the component, but this change didn't happen automatically.

The solution above worked for me. I would love something more elegant.

Comment: The answer here is to use `Vue.set(state.votes, newVotesObject)` in your mutations

Comment: Here is a working example without the workarounds and a bit cleaner: https://codepen.io/d-pollard/pen/NWrYKme?editors=1010

Comment: Another working example with dynamic options: https://codepen.io/d-pollard/pen/WNxzNbW?editors=1011

Comment: @DerekPollard `Vue.set()` isn't always helpful, for instance if you happen to be importing non-reactive data into your Vuex state or into your Vue component.

Answer (score 13):

if you use typescript then you can :

```js
import { Watch } from "vue-property-decorator";

..

@Watch("$store.state.something")
private watchSomething() {
   // use this.$store.state.something for access
   ...
}
```

Comment: Why exactly was this downvoted? Just because the solution is for vue-class-component and the TO was asking for old vue-class styles? I find the former preferable. Maybe @Zhang Sol could mention in the introduction, that this is explicitly for vue-class-component?

Comment: Note sure why a typescript decorator would be preferable to a vue native solution as simple as this one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56461539/3652783

Comment: @yann_yinn well, because your example won't work with typescript component

Comment: @Desprit true but the question was not using nor mentionning TypeScript. But still a useful tip for Typscript users for sure.

Answer (score 13):

If you simply want to **watch** a **state property** and then act within the component accordingly to the changes of that property then see the example below.

In `store.js`:

```
export const state = () => ({
 isClosed: false
})
export const mutations = {
 closeWindow(state, payload) {
  state.isClosed = payload
 }
}
```

In this scenario, I am creating a `boolean` state property that I am going to change in different places in the application like so:

```
this.$store.commit('closeWindow', true)
```

Now, if I need to watch that state property in some other component and then change the local property I would write the following in the `mounted` hook:

```
mounted() {
 this.$store.watch(
  state => state.isClosed,
  (value) => {
   if (value) { this.localProperty = 'edit' }
  }
 )
}
```

Firstly, I am setting a watcher on the state property and then in the callback function I use the `value` of that property to change the `localProperty`.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 7):

The best way to watch store changes is to use `mapGetters` as Gabriel said.
But there is a case when you can't do it through `mapGetters` e.g. you want to get something from store using parameter:

```
getters: {
  getTodoById: (state, getters) => (id) => {
    return state.todos.find(todo => todo.id === id)
  }
}
```

in that case you can't use `mapGetters`. You may try to do something like this instead:

```
computed: {
    todoById() {
        return this.$store.getters.getTodoById(this.id)
    }
}
```

But unfortunately `todoById` [will be updated only if `this.id` is changed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#ad)

If you want you component update in such case use `this.$store.watch` [solution provided by Gong](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/api.html#vuexstore-instance-methods). Or handle your component consciously and update `this.id` when you need to update `todoById`.

Comment: At least in my case which is slightly different `return this.$store.getters.getTodoById({id: this.id})` not sure if it's the object that causes this not to be reactive... but it's not reactive.

Answer (score 7):

Create a **Local state** of your store variable by watching and setting on value changes.
Such that the local variable changes for **form-input v-model** does not directly mutate the **store variable**.

```
data() {
  return {
    localState: null
  };
 },
 computed: {
  ...mapGetters({
    computedGlobalStateVariable: 'state/globalStateVariable'
  })
 },
 watch: {
  computedGlobalStateVariable: 'setLocalState'
 },
 methods: {
  setLocalState(value) {
   this.localState = Object.assign({}, value);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

Use your getter in computed then watch it and do what you need

```
    computed:{
    ...mapGetters(["yourGetterName"])
 },
 watch: {
    yourGetterName(value) {
       // Do something you need
    },

  }
```

Answer (score 6):

You could also subscribe to the store mutations:

```
store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
  console.log(mutation.type)
  console.log(mutation.payload)
})
```

https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#subscribe

Comment: You can fire this in the beforeMount() hook of your component then filter the incoming mutations with an if Statement. e.g if( mutation.type == "names/SET_NAMES") {... do something }

Answer (score 6):

Inside the component, create a computed function

```
computed:{
  myState:function(){
    return this.$store.state.my_state; // return the state value in `my_state`
  }
}
```

Now the computed function name can be watched, like

```
watch:{
  myState:function(newVal,oldVal){
    // this function will trigger when ever the value of `my_state` changes
  }
}
```

The changes made in the `vuex` state `my_state` will reflect in the computed function `myState` and trigger the watch function.

If the state `my_state` is having nested data, then the `handler` option will help more

```
watch:{
  myState:{
    handler:function(newVal,oldVal){
      // this function will trigger when ever the value of `my_state` changes
    },
    deep:true
  }
}
```

This will watch all the nested values in the store `my_state`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a combination of Vuex [actions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html), [getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html), [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) and [watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) to listen to changes on a Vuex state value.

HTML Code:

```
<div id="app" :style='style'>
  <input v-model='computedColor' type="text" placeholder='Background Color'>
</div>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
'use strict'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const { mapGetters, mapActions, Store } = Vuex

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  store: new Store({
    state: {
      color: 'red'
    },
    getters: {
      color({color}) {
        return color
      }
    },
    mutations: {
      setColor(state, payload) {
        state.color = payload
      }
    },
    actions: {
      setColor({commit}, payload) {
        commit('setColor', payload)
      }
    }
  }),
  methods: {
    ...mapGetters([
        'color'
    ]),
    ...mapActions([
        'setColor'
    ])
  },
  computed: {
    computedColor: {
        set(value) {
        this.setColor(value)
      },
      get() {
        return this.color()
      }
    },
    style() {
        return `background-color: ${this.computedColor};`
    }
  },
  watch: {
    computedColor() {
        console.log(`Watcher in use @${new Date().getTime()}`)
    }
  }
})
```

[See JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1L1n8nzp/).

Answer (score 4):

When you want to watch on state level, it can be done this way:

```
let App = new Vue({
    //...
    store,
    watch: {
        '$store.state.myState': function (newVal) {
            console.log(newVal);
            store.dispatch('handleMyStateChange');
        }
    },
    //...
});
```

Comment: It's not good idea to handle `store.state` change by `dispatch` state action from component as this behaviour only work if you use that component. Also you might ended with infinite loop.
Watch to `store.state` change rarely use, for example if you have a component or a page that should do some action based on `store.state` changed that could not handled by using computed mapState only where you cannot compare `newValue` vs `oldValue`

Comment: @Januartha what is your suggestion to this problem then?

Comment: @Andy yes of course its work. I just want to note why you call `store.dispatch`? if you want to handle `store.state` change for `store' why not handle it inside `store.mutations` ?

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ I prever **dube** solution is more cleaner

Comment: @Januartha, because there might be an ajax call to happen before doing a mutation, that's why i use `store.dispatch` first. For example, i want to get all the cities from a country whenever `$store.state.country` changes, so i add this to the watcher. Then i would write an ajax call: in `store.dispatch('fetchCities')` i write: `axios.get('cities',{params:{country: state.country }}).then(response => store.commit('receiveCities',response) )`

Answer (score 1):

Vue watch in string state

**state:**

```
$store.state.local_store.list_of_data
```

inside component

```
  watch: {
       
       '$store.state.local_store.list_of_data':{//<----------your state call in string
        handler(){
            console.log("value changeing in party sales entry"); //<---do your stuff here
        },
        deep:true
       }

    },
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple method in which I use computed is something like this. May be it is of any help to you.

```
  const variable_name = computed(
        () => store.state.[name_of_state].property_name
      );
```

Another version in which you can do this is

```
computed: {
  name () {
    return this.$store.state.[name_of_state].property
  }
}
```

This is a format of accessing the getter from the store.
Hope you have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use mapState in your vue component to direct getting state from store.

In your component:

```
computed: mapState([
  'my_state'
])
```

Where `my_state` is a variable from the store.

Answer (score 0):

```js
====== store =====
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    showRegisterLoginPage: true,
    user: null,
    allitem: null,
    productShow: null,
    userCart: null
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_USERS(state, payload) {
      state.user = payload
    },
    HIDE_LOGIN(state) {
      state.showRegisterLoginPage = false
    },
    SHOW_LOGIN(state) {
      state.showRegisterLoginPage = true
    },
    SET_ALLITEM(state, payload) {
      state.allitem = payload
    },
    SET_PRODUCTSHOW(state, payload) {
      state.productShow = payload
    },
    SET_USERCART(state, payload) {
      state.userCart = payload
    }
  },
  actions: {
    getUserLogin({ commit }) {
      axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/users',
        headers: {
          token: localStorage.getItem('token')
        }
      })
        .then(({ data }) => {
          // console.log(data)
          commit('SET_USERS', data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    },
    addItem({ dispatch }, payload) {
      let formData = new FormData()
      formData.append('name', payload.name)
      formData.append('file', payload.file)
      formData.append('category', payload.category)
      formData.append('price', payload.price)
      formData.append('stock', payload.stock)
      formData.append('description', payload.description)
      axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/products',
        data: formData,
        headers: {
          token: localStorage.getItem('token')
        }
      })
        .then(({ data }) => {
          // console.log('data hasbeen created ', data)
          dispatch('getAllItem')
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    },
    getAllItem({ commit }) {
      axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/products'
      })
        .then(({ data }) => {
          // console.log(data)
          commit('SET_ALLITEM', data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    },
    addUserCart({ dispatch }, { payload, productId }) {
      let newCart = {
        count: payload
      }
      // console.log('ini dari store nya', productId)

      axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: `http://localhost:3000/transactions/${productId}`,
        data: newCart,
        headers: {
          token: localStorage.getItem('token')
        }
      })
        .then(({ data }) => {
          dispatch('getUserCart')
          // console.log('cart hasbeen added ', data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    },
    getUserCart({ commit }) {
      axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/transactions/user',
        headers: {
          token: localStorage.getItem('token')
        }
      })
        .then(({ data }) => {
          // console.log(data)
          commit('SET_USERCART', data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    },
    cartCheckout({ commit, dispatch }, transactionId) {
      let count = null
      axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: `http://localhost:3000/transactions/checkout/${transactionId}`,
        headers: {
          token: localStorage.getItem('token')
        },
        data: {
          sesuatu: 'sesuatu'
        }
      })
        .then(({ data }) => {
          count = data.count
          console.log(count, data)

          dispatch('getUserCart')
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    },
    deleteTransactions({ dispatch }, transactionId) {
      axios({
        method: 'delete',
        url: `http://localhost:3000/transactions/${transactionId}`,
        headers: {
          token: localStorage.getItem('token')
        }
      })
        .then(({ data }) => {
          console.log('success delete')

          dispatch('getUserCart')
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    }
  },
  modules: {}
})
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Putting only a code snippet is not enough. Please provide some explanations about your code.

Answer (score 0):

I used this way and it works:

store.js:

```
const state = {
  createSuccess: false
};
```

mutations.js

```
[mutations.CREATE_SUCCESS](state, payload) {
    state.createSuccess = payload;
}
```

actions.js

```
async [mutations.STORE]({ commit }, payload) {
  try {
    let result = await axios.post('/api/admin/users', payload);
    commit(mutations.CREATE_SUCCESS, user);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

getters.js

```
isSuccess: state => {
    return state.createSuccess
}
```

And in your component where you use state from store:

```
watch: {
    isSuccess(value) {
      if (value) {
        this.$notify({
          title: "Success",
          message: "Create user success",
          type: "success"
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

When user submit form, action **STORE** will be call, after created success, **CREATE_SUCCESS** mutation is committed after that. Turn **createSuccess** is true, and in component, watcher will see value has changed and trigger notification.

**isSuccess** should be match with the name you declare in **getters.js**

Answer (score 0):

You can also watch it safely with debouncedWatch (vue use function)

```
  debouncedWatch(
    lines,
    () => {
      console.log('changed');
    },
    500,
  );
```