# How to watch two more stores in Vue.js and Vuex?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I'm using Vue.js and Vuex.
I want to `watch` the value of `store` (I'll share my sample codes in the last of this post).
But I have encountered the error "Error: [vuex] store.watch only accepts a function."

In this Web site, I found how to use "single" store.
https://codepen.io/CodinCat/pen/PpNvYr

However, in my case, I want to use "two" stores.
Do you have any idea to solve this problem.

●index.js

```
'use strict';
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

import {test1Store} from './modules/test1.js';
import {test2Store} from './modules/test2.js';

Vue.use(Vuex);
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        test1: test1Store,
        test2: tes21Store,
    }
});
```

●test1.js

```
'use strict';
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);
export const checkerStore = {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        count: 1
    },

    getters: {
        getCount(state){
            return state.count;
        }
    }
};
export default {test1};
```

●test.vue

```
<template>
    {{ $store.state.couunt }}
</template>

<script>
    import {store} from './store/index.js';
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {

            }
        },
        store: store,
        methods: {

        },
        mounted() {
            setInterval(() => { this.$store.state.count++ }, 1000);
            this.$store.watch(this.$store.getters['test1/getCount'], n => {
                console.log('watched: ', n)
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vuejs 2 how to watch store values from vuex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43270159/vuejs-2-how-to-watch-store-values-from-vuex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because in your example code, the first argument you've passed to `watch` is, as the error suggests, not a `function`.

The argument is actually implemented using the native JavaScript call [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) underneath the hood by Vue, so the result of doing `store.getters['test1/getCount']` as you have, is actually a `number`.

I don't think it's recommended to use `watch` in a scenario like yours, but if you insist, you can access `count` by providing an alternate argument form, something like:

```
this.$store.watch((state, getters) => getters['test1/getCount'], n => { ... })
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! 
I can solve my problem and work well with your suggestion code.

If you can, I want to know why you said `I don't think it's recommended to use watch in a scenario like yours`.

Thanks,

Comment: @ketancho, no problem, I'm glad my answer helped. As for my recommendation remark, I'm not sure exactly what you're doing inside the `watch` callback, but if you're simply responding to the state change by using the new value to calculate something else, using a `computed` property is a much cleaner way of accomplishing this. In case you missed it, the [official documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html) has great examples concerning this.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! 
I try to read official document in detail and think which is better way in my case.

Thanks!!!!