# How to watch for state change in Vuex properly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm using below code to watch for the change in Vuex state. The store file lies in the same directory. However, it doesn't seem to work. How do I watch for state change in vuex properly?

```
import store from './index'
store.watch(
  (store) => store.state.base_url,
  () => {
    console.log('Watcher works')
  }
)
```

Comment: is this what your trying to do? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43270159/vuejs-2-how-to-watch-store-values-from-vuex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you're just not using `watch` correctly? According to the [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#watch), the watch function receives the store's state as the first argument, so it should be:

```
store.watch(
  state => state.base_url,
  () => console.log('Watcher works')
)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but the problem seems to be somewhere else, that didn't solve it.

Comment: Unfortunately without any additional information we won't be able to help you much further.

Comment: @ShubhamChaudhary Don't know if it could be this, but try using named import instead of default import. `import {store} from './index'`. Otherwise provide more information on your store.