# Computed Property does not get updated when state changes

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

We are trying to detect whether a person is logged in or not using the `vuex` store state: `loggedIn`. When I call the API service from the action it calls the `mutation` after successful login and changes the data in the state:

```
loginSuccess(state, accessToken) {
    state.accessToken = accessToken;
    state.authenticating = false;
    state.loggedIn = true;
    console.log(state.loggedIn);
  }
```

The `console.log()` shows the value, so the mutation is working.

In my other component, I use a computed property to watch for changes in the store using `...mapState()` and bound the property in the template view:

```
computed: { 
    ...mapState('authStore',['loggedIn' ]);
  }
```

But the view never gets updated based on the computed property. I checked using the Vue dev tools in the console. It shows the state changes.

I have initialized the state.

```
export const states = {
  loggedIn: false
};
```

I have tried to call the state directly.

```
this.$store.state.authStore.loggedIn;
```

I have tried different approaches.

```
...mapState('authStore', { logging:'loggedIn' });
//or
...mapState('authStore',['loggedIn' ]);
```

also, tried `watch: {}` hook but not working.

**Interestingly though, the state's `getter` always shows `undefined`, but the state property changes in the dev tools.**

Cannot figure out what is wrong or how to move further.

here is the screenshot of devtools `state` after successful login:

[image: after login success]

Comment: Does this help at all?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43270159/vuejs-2-how-to-watch-store-values-from-vuex

Comment: Also, it's `state` in singular: vuex.vuejs.org/api/#state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This catches my eye:

```js
export const states = {
  loggedIn: false
};
```

My suspicion is that you're then trying to use it something like this:

```js
const store = {
  states,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters
}
```

This won't work because it needs to be called `state` and not `states`. The result will be that `loggedIn` is unreactive and has an initial value of `undefined`. Any computed properties, including the store's getter, will not be refreshed when the value changes.

Whether my theory is right or not, I suggest adding `console.log(state.loggedIn);` to the beginning of `loginSucess` to confirm the state prior to the mutation.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Skirtle for your solution.we stuck for 2 days for this . :D

Comment: you have a really sharp eye! thanks for your reply. missed that myself too.

Comment: It comes to my attention that `state` should be singular: https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#state. And if you are using SSR (say, with Nuxt), you also wan't your state be a function that returns an object

Comment: @PaulMelero I'm not sure what point you're making. My answer already explains that it is `state` and not `states`. As for SSR, that doesn't seem relevant to the question that was asked.

Comment: You're right. I didn't see that on your answer. The SSR part maight be useful for other folks.