# How do I run a function on a different component with vuex (non parent/child components)

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have 2 non parent/child components.
I'd like to run a function on component A by clicking a button on component B.
I know that the eventbus is a solution but because I am already using Vuex I would like to do it the Vuex way but could not find an example on the internet.

Comment: Please post your code it will help to understand refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have component A mutate some state that component B is watching. When component B see's a change to that state, run your function.

The mutation could be as simple as flipping a boolean or incrementing a number. Anything to trigger the watch in the other component.

Here is how to setup the watch: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44347195/1409310