# How to watch for state change in Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm using below code to watch for the change in Vuex state but watch is not working. I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'watch' of undefined

**acl.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { AclInstaller, AclCreate, AclRule } from 'vue-acl'
import router from '@/router'
import axios from '../axios'
import { store } from '../store/store'

Vue.use(AclInstaller)

store.watch(state => state.auth.token, (val) => {
    if (val) {
      console.log(val)
    }
  }
)

export default new AclCreate({
  initial: 'admin',
  notfound: '/pages/not-authorized',
  router,
  acceptLocalRules: true,
  globalRules: new AclRule('admin').generate(),
})
```

**store.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import auth from "./auth";

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({    
    modules: {
      auth: auth
    },
    strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
})
```

Comment: import store from '../store/store' instead of import { store } from '../store/store'?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43270159/vue-js-2-how-to-watch-store-values-from-vuex