# VueJS sever-side-rendering: computed property not seeing changes in store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to get server side rendering to work in VueJS.

I've been following the official docs, and I'm attempting to get this example to work using axios. The endpoint is correct and the data does show up in the `mutation`.

https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/data.html

I also found this page and tried most of these examples, which includes using getters, vuex mapState, mapGetter, etc:

[vue.js 2 how to watch store values from vuex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43270159/vue-js-2-how-to-watch-store-values-from-vuex)

Here is `store/index.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

import { fetchPage } from './api'

export function createStore () {
    return new Vuex.Store({
        strict: true,

        state: () => ({
            res: {}
        }),

        actions: {
            actXY ({ commit }, page) {
                fetchPage('homepage').then((item) => {
                    commit('mutXY', { page, item });
                }).catch(error => {
                    throw new Error(`Store ${error}`);

                })
            }
        },

        mutations: {
            mutXY (state, { page, item }) {
                Vue.set(state.res, page, item);
                console.log(state.res.homepage.data)

            }
        },

        getters: {
            getXY (state) {
                return state.res
            }
        }
    })
}
```

the console log is displaying the correct information, so that means the axios endpoint is working and updating the state object. Originally, I was attempting to call the `mutation`, but I've since tried calling the `getter`. Unfortunately, the new data is not being updated in the `getter`, so of course, nothing new shows up in the component.

This is `HomePage.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="htmlData">{{ JSON.stringify(htmlData) }}</div>
  <div v-else>loading?</div>
</template>

<script>
export default ({
    name: 'homepage',

    computed: {
        htmlData () {
            console.log("computed = " + JSON.stringify(this.$store.state.res));
            console.log(this.$store.getters.getXY);
            return this.$store.getters
            // return this.getQuery()
        }
    },

    serverPrefetch () {
        return this.getData()
    },

    mounted () {
        console.log("in mounted")
        if (!this.item) {
            this.getData()
        }
    },

    methods: {
        getData () {
            return this.$store.dispatch('actXY', 'homepage')
        }
    }
})

</script>
```

As written, `htmlData` will show:

```
{"getXY":{}}
```

Yes, I did attempt many other variations on how to return the store item in the `getter,` but nothing is working.

Aside from the stuff in the above links, I've also looked around for variations on config files, I attempted to add `async` to store/actions, getData(), etc.

I also attempted to make the axios call directly in the component, which has had no success.

Since this is a project that was already more-or-less completed in VueJS that I'm converting to SSR, I removed everything from package.json and reinstalled every package, in the hopes that maybe one of the old vue packages was causing a conflict.

I also attempted the store code splitting from the official docs, and tried variations on how the routes are written. Nothing at all works.

I think I should add what the print statements show when I run my current code:

```
computed = undefined
computed mm  = undefined
getter = {}
computed get  = {"getXY":{}}
{
  title: 'Home'...}
```

The computed property in the component runs *before* the mutation is set. This causes the getter to be called before the mutation is updated. Likewise, if I'm attempting to call changes to `res` directly from the component, there is nothing in mutations when the store is being called and rendered.

This is a repo of the code I'm attempting to run: https://github.com/dt1/vue-ssr-attempt

(I figured out the answer. I've updated the repo with what is working for me, and explanation of my solution is below)

Comment: Why you dont use Nuxt.js ?

Comment: Not sure if it's related - on mounted you call this.fetchItem, but I can't see it's declaration. Am I missing something?

Comment: @KarinC, mounted is never called in server side rendering. I know it's confusing to have the artifact there, but it doesn't cause any issues at this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured this out.

The main issues I ran into were the out-of-order calls. When I fixed the ordering, I was running into `Converting circular structure to JSON` errors. Next was trying to understand how the callbacks function between VueJS, Vuex stores, and axios.

The final solution I came up with is:

`store/index.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import * as util from 'util'

Vue.use(Vuex)

import { fetchPage } from './api'

export function createStore () {
    return new Vuex.Store({
        strict: true,

        state: () => ({
            res: {}
        }),

        actions: {
            actXY ({ commit }, page) {
                return fetchPage(page).then(item => {
                    commit('mutXY', { page , item } );
                })
            }
        },

        mutations: {
            mutXY (state, {page, item }) {
                Vue.set(state.res, page, item);
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Then when making the axios call, I had to be sure to return only the `response.data` instead of the entire response. Before this, I getting a `unhandled promise` error.

`api.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

Vue.axios.defaults.baseURL = '<url goes here>';

export function fetchPage(page){
    return Vue.axios.get(page).then((resp => resp.data))
}
```

Last but not least, this is `Homepage.vue`.

In order to fire an update, I had to make getData() asynchronous:

```
<template>
<div v-if="htmlData">
  <div>{{ htmlData.title }}</div>
  <div>{{ htmlData.description }}</div>
  <div>{{ htmlData.html }}</div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default ({
    name: 'homepage',
    computed: {
        htmlData () {
            return this.$store.state.res.homepage
        }
    },

    serverPrefetch () {
        return this.getData()
    },
    mounted () {
        if (!this.item) {
            this.getData()
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async getData () {
            await this.$store.dispatch('actXY', 'homepage')
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

Hopefully this helps anyone who's running into all of these issues.

Answer (score 1):

First `storeData()` => `storeData(state)`

then `return this.$store.state.items.homepage.data` => `return this.$store.state.items.homepage && return this.$store.state.items.homepage.data` (or initialize the state items with an empty homepage)

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Why is there a &&?

Comment: Because this.$store.state.items.homepage is initially undefined, until the data are comited. You don't want to access .data property of undefined ;) You should have an error message in the console regarding that.

Comment: shouldn't it be `this.getData()` instead of `this.fetchItem()` in the mounted hook?

Comment: I left the mount in there by accident. It doesn't matter with SSR since mounted never runs. I removed it, updated, etc, but nothing happens.

Comment: There is no error popping up. That's the issue, "computed" doesn't fire at all. If I add a watch property, computed will at least log out the "computed here", but there is no rendering or errors. It's very confusing.

Comment: Did you try `return this.$store.state.items.homepage && return this.$store.state.items.homepage.data` for the item computed? We'll try to move forward from there.

Comment: Nothing happens. The $this.store is just the default mapping, like this `{"items":{},"route":{"name":"homepage"....}`, even inside `computed` after adding a watcher. It's also strange because `getter` can't seem to see any state changes either.

Comment: If you could set-up a minimal reproduction that would help greatly I think (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

There is no SSR in Vue.js [out of the box](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html).
In your example you can get data on client.

Try this example for Store:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  state: {
    res: null
  },
  getters: {
    getXY(state) {
      return state.res;
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    mutXY(state, payload) {
      state.res = payload;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    actXY: function(store) {
      fetchPage("homepage")
        .then(res => {
          store.commit("mutXY", res);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          throw new Error(`Store ${error}`);
        });
    }
  }
});
```

And you can get data in the component as such:

```
  computed: {
    htmlData() {
      return this.$store.getters.getXY;
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getData();
  },
  methods: {
    getData() {
      return this.$store.dispatch("actXY", "homepage");
    }
  }
```

Comment: The only way I'm able to get getters to work is if I use a watcher in my component. Asdie from this, the store data is invisible in getters. It seems that, once the data is set in the mutations property, it is locally-scoped and can't be seen anywhere else.

Comment: Maybe it's due to Vue.set() in your mutation. Please try example of mutation that I've added above.

Comment: Tried that, but still the same issue

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: I'm aware that SSR isn't out of the box. I've been configuring this for an entire week now, and `{"getXY":{}}` does show up in view source. If I log `state` in getters or the compenent, it only shows the original `res` object, with now new information, and this is the issue. Whatever is in mutations cannot be seen outside of mutations.

Answer (score 1):

My question is why is the `this.getData()` called in mounted?

If I understand the process correctly, when you call server side rendering you are trying to render the HTML before the vue component is mounted. Would it work if you called `this.getData()` in created instead of mounted?

Other things I would try:

1. hardcode htmlData value in component to check if it would render
2. if that works, hardcode htmlData value in store and check if the component can fetch that store data and render properly too
3. after that works too, fetch htmlData from server via dispatch from the component, see if it works.
4. if (3) does not work, try pushing the htmlData to a child component 
   that is created only when you already have htmlData ready, send
   htmlData to the child component via props

Comment: The mounted is just copy/paste from the docs. I had it removed before and it didn't make a difference (as expected). `serverPrefetch` is apparently the correct way to instantiate the store. I did try `created` and it doesn't work. I'm going to try out your other ideas and see what happens.

Comment: Okay, when I hard-code a return value of the map in the `fetchPage` function, the data is returned successfully. Seems the issue is when I'm using axios, the data does return, but then it is squashed right away, maybe?

Comment: Tried plan 4 with the props. The prop can fire but nothing will render. The data doesn't even get into mutations when doing that, so it's just an empty object.

Comment: so a hard-code fetchPage function works, but when you have to wait for axios it does not return anything. I suspect it is because the component you are trying to render has finished rendering before axios returns the value. So at (4) I tried to recreate the hard-code fetchPage by having data ready before creating the component. However I didn't expect the props to not work. If you tried <div>{{ htmlData }}</div> it becomes just empty object?

Comment: That is correct, getter and mutation comes back as an empty object. The data from axios does return, it prints out in mutation but does not print out in getters. When the component calls the mutation directly, there is no data returned either.

Comment: Actually, forgot to mention, that actions, mutations, and getters did fire twice when I did v4.

Comment: it fires twice, so the first time it fire it does get the htmlData from server, but then it fires again and the data is gone?

Comment: Where I am right now, the component would fire twist while using props. The actions and mutations fire once each, but then there would be no data in mutations.

Comment: hi, it's been awhile but I found something that might be useful https://ssr.vuejs.org/#about-this-guide about ssr in vue. seems you have to install an extra package and add an extra attribute to the html DOM for it to "hydrate" properly https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/hydration.html