# watching a vuex state inside nested modules and login its value in a component whenever it changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, watch, state-management

I know a similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43270159/how-to-watch-store-values-from-vuex) but mine is a little bit different, the state I want to watch is inside some nested
modules. on the link above they suggested I can watch the state like this:

```
watch: {
  '$store.state.drawer': function() {
    console.log(this.$store.state.drawer)
  }
}
```

But my state is in nested modules as I mentioned, something like `store/moduleOne/moduleTwo/moduleThree` They suggested to do this:

```
$store.state.moduleOne.moduleTwo.moduleThree.something
```

But I tried it and many more variations and it didn't work! I asked on the original post and no answers!

So my question is how can I watch a state, let's call it `price` and let's say it's in `store/moduleOne/moduleTwo/moduleThree` and then log its value in my component whenever it changes using (using `map` functionalities is no problem and is preferred)

Comment: That might not be a good practice, as much as possible make it only 1 level,
The watcher or vue devtools might not track its changes due to level of nested and will cause drawback in future

Comment: Do you have getter for this state?

Comment: You can watch for getter instead, like **$store.getters.GET_STATE_TO_WATCH**

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming nested modules declared in Vuex 4 like this:*

```js
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
  modules: {
    moduleOne: {
      namespaced: true,
      modules: {
        moduleTwo: {
          namespaced: true,
          modules: {
            moduleThree: {
              namespaced: true,
              state: () => ({
                price: 0,
              }),
              mutations: {
                SET_PRICE(state, price) {
                  state.price = price
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```

...the watcher on the `price` state in `moduleThree` would be:

```js
export default {
  watch: {
    '$store.state.moduleOne.moduleTwo.moduleThree.price'(price) {
      console.log({ price })
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-set-nested-module-state-in-vuex?file=src/App.vue)